# How to power a 24V 2.5A DC motor with a switching power supply?

Tags: motor, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, 24v

I need to power a windshield wiper motor at 24V. Switching mode power supply shuts off.

The motor, rated 50 W, runs at 12V (50 RPM) or 24V (110 RPM).  It's exactly the same one this guy has in [this youtube video.](https://youtu.be/id5usTwHwtY)

[image]

**PROBLEM**

I have a a 24V 5A switching power supply that works fine with a 24V incandescent lamp. But if I connect the motor, it spins for less than a second and the power supply shuts off (the onboard LED turns off.) I'm pretty sure the inrush current skyrockets briefly and causes the shutdown.

**QUESTION**
Is it possible to power the motor using my current PS?

What do I need exactly?

I don't need variable speed control or anything fancy or expensive.

Comment: You either need a PSU that can handle the startup current (aka stall current) of the motor, or you need a motor controller that allows you to "soft start" the motor (ramp up the drive voltage over a few seconds)

Comment: Measure the resistance of the motor and then use that to work out the current required to start it using Ohm's law \$ I = \frac V R \$.

Comment: And the youtube clip is a music video....

Comment: Meassured the resistance: 1.3 Ohms. That's 18.5 A!

I believe I'll definitely need a "soft start" and ramp up the current..
Is there any specific term for this controller?

Thank you so much,
btw, fixed the youtube video link. I was listening to that on another browser tab, oops!

Comment: what part of my answer did you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR ( get an 8 Ohm @ 25'C, not the hot R " @ current ", Inrush Current Limiters ICL from D-K) These come like radial ceramic caps or in SMT format.

> (TL;DR is the modern vernacular for Too Long {and lazy}; Didn't Read)

These are Metal Oxide NTC's (Neg. TempCo's) that have the opposite thermal characteristics of PTC's used for soft current limiting protection. (like a slow-blow fuse)

### For those that wish to understand.

A common misunderstanding in driving motors is that all one needs is the rated Voltage * current= Power in an SMPS to drive it. It starts at DC so the inductive impedance is 0 + DCR. Coil DCR is ~ 10% rated electro-mechanical R=load V/Imax.

DC motors kike this were designed to run off lead-acid batteries with slow blow fuses.  You could in fact run off a small 12V SLA battery with a proper trickle charger.

\$R_{eq.rated}=V/I = 12V/2.5A= \text{~}5~ \Omega~  (Ohms) \$ We expect typical motor DCR  to be about 10% or 0.5 Ω but your comment indicates measured DCR was 1.3 Ω or 26%. ( but then car batteries operate @ 14.2 V nom and sometimes 14.6V a marginal spec.)

- Actually the rated voltage depends on the thermal capacity to remove heat under load for a specific max temp such as 85'C.

  - You measured 1.3 ohms so operating overvoltage results in a start current of 24V/1.3Ω = 18.5A

> Remember DCR is the result of many turns of copper around the motor core so it has a resistance which just generates heat, but high surge current = torque, while the motor inductance raises impedance with RPM commutation.

In a car operating with 14.2 to 14.5V that's  14.5V/1.3Ω= 11.2A

> Conventional tungsten lamps (and/or halogen tungsten) have a similar starting current due to a low cold thermal resistance which is about 10% of hot. Yet the PTC tempco rises much faster than a motor RPM so Motors often triggers SMPS current or temperature protection circuits called OCP & OTP, unless they have massive heatsinks with transient power loss capacity.  So your 50 W bulb does not stay cold long enough to simulate a motor.

### Options:

- soft start = ICL. Inrush Current Limiter, a Metal oxide varistor with an NTC instead of a PTC oxide thermal resistor so it runs hot until the motor speeds up and currents drop to cool the PTC below 85'C (common ) threshold where the resistance starts to change rapidly. This is like the solution of @CharlesCowie but not offered {here} for huge industrial motors.

[image]

> Here's a rough estimate of the ideal value which depends on the desired start and holding current.

Since your SMPS is rated for 24V/2.5A=9.6 Ohms and motor DCR is 1.3 Ω  you can choose an Inrush Current Limiter around 9.6-1.3= 8.3 Ohms cold {give or take your tolerances.}  Choose (In stock) and nearest values so you can get a bunch of them as they are cheaper than shipping costs.[image]

- 24V small battery pack with ESR << 1 Ohm kept constant with 24V SMPS to make up the steady-state current. ( Again can't charge this if Vbat << 24V) and demands > 2.5A This depends on size, chemistry and balanced condition of each cell as ESR adds up (but also shorter lifespan on brushes from the more serious carbon brush arcing (>5000'C) when turned on/off.)
- a bigger power capacity SMPS

[image]
[image]

You can vary R choices by running 2x in parallel to some extent but depends on user skills of thermal matching to work together in a layout.

Comment: Hi Tony! Thanks for your kind and detailed reply. It's really useful and I learned a lot. Apreciate it!

Comment: @spacefolder that’s good to know. When I was an aerospace Design engineer rookie, I was afraid to my old prof’s how to design impedance spectrum splitter for my 2 way RF links, baseband audio FDX and RF TV, so don’t be the same as I was in 1976

Comment: Afraid. To ask for help from my...

Comment: Hi Tony, I got the NTCs and.. they work!
I found a local electronic components shop which had 10 Ohm NTC Varistors.

QUESTION: Using 1 NTC (10 Ohm), the motor spins up almost instantaneously, and seems to be spinning at max speed (110 rpm). But the NTC gets REALLY hot (I can't touch it for more than 1-2 seconds). Do they operate SO hot, or is too much current circulating through it?

I tried putting 2 NTCs in series. They still get hot, and the motor spins too slow for my needs.

VIDEOS:
10 OHM NTC + MOTOR: https://youtu.be/iNh79Ewqh0A
20 OHM NTC + MOTOR: https://youtu.be/xXcLlmAt2K8

Comment: Yes theyaredesignbedtorunhot and my space bar was stuck.. 85’C AFAIK and 55’C burns, so get a higher current rating slightly or put in parallel.  You can calculate the optimal R for temp rise and Is trade off

Answer (score 3):

Prior to the invention of the transistor, DC motors were started by putting a resistor or several in series with the motor and then shorting them out either manually or with timed relays.

The diagram below shows a manual starter for a DC motor. The resistors connected in series with the armature of the DC motor are progressively bypassed by manually moving a lever. The resistor values are selected to hold the peak current to 125 to 175 percent of the full-load current of the motor.

[image]

Comment: The resistor with the timed relay might be a quick and cheap solution. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a power supply which restricts output current but doesn't shut it off. Even in that case the power supply should provide enough current to create torque.

The start current is just voltage divided by active resistance, measured with ohmmeter.

In your case the motor has a gear drive as a load, so the start current should be bigger - 5 amperes is not enough.

Comment: You're right, the estimated current is about 18 A. But I'm looking at other solutions... 20 A is too much! Thank you!

Comment: From my experience motor to start need approximately half of working voltage. But it may depend on mechanical load on the motor. Try power supply with current restriction around 10 amps. For example if a nominal current 8 amps overcurrent protection may start at 10 amps.